# Is it possible to delete issues on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I recently installed GitLab to try it out and I am really enjoying it. It's very easy to install and use, still, I found an annoying "problem". I haven't yet found a way to delete Issues associated to projects.

I know that it's not a good practice to remove Issues from the system, but there are some specific occasions where this is really useful, such as when you create an Issue that makes no sense and don't want to be in the system, even after being closed.

So, my question, really simple: Is it possible to delete Issues on GitLab? If so, how can I do it?

I am using GitLab 7.2.1, on Debian wheezy.

Many thanks

Answer (score 27):

It is now possible to delete issues starting with GitLab 8.6:

[GitLab 8.6 released with Deploy to Kubernetes and Subscribe to Label](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/22/gitlab-8-6-released/)

> **Delete Issues**
>
> Sometimes, simply closing an issue or merge request is not sufficient. For those times, we are now making it possible to delete issues and merge requests.
>
> Only `owners` can delete issues by editing the issue or merge request and clicking, you guessed it, `Delete`.

Comment: How do I become `owner`? I'm using GitLab Community Edition 9.5 and am the `master` of the project I want to delete a dummy issue I created from (which would make me think that I'm the `owner` too, but there's no delete button on the issue's page).

Comment: I'm the user who created this repo, and there's no delete button as stated.

Comment: +1 `owner` correspond to the username that created the issue. You can become owner using the sudo: <creator_username> option in headers

Comment: Official documentation : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#deleting-issues

Comment: @c24b `owner` is a role associated to the group or project, not to the specific issue; so the creator of the issue could have no permission to delete it; to verify your role inside a project, check the project members page ;)

Comment: Note that the comment from @c24b is not correct since the owner is the one who created the repo, not the one who created the issue.

Answer (score 7):

At the time this question was asked, No. There is a feature request for that at: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2489

Now it seems possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36172116/895245

Comment: @WarrenP approved!

Answer (score 7):

Click the `Edit` button (Pencil icon for editing the text of the issue)

Below and to the right of the text box where you can enter the description is a big red `Delete` button. Click it and confirm.

Personally, I find the hiding of a `Delete` button behind the `Edit` button and right next to a pretty unrelated `Cancel` button to be very unintuitive and weird.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that any more.

> **Delete existing issue (Deprecated)**
>
> The function is deprecated and returns a **405 Method Not Allowed** error
>   if called. An issue gets now closed and is done by calling **PUT
>   /projects/:id/issues/:issue_id** with parameter **closed** set to 1.
>
> `DELETE /projects/:id/issues/:issue_id`
>
> Parameters:
>
> **id** (required) - The project ID
>
> **issue_id** (required) - The ID of the
>   issue

Ref: [GitLab Documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html)

Comment: That's a bummer... Thanks!

Comment: And you can do it again, after 8.6+ reinstated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but have to modify the database manually. If you have a backup, you can give it a try.

Update: Possible since GitLab 8.6.

Comment: Highly dangerous.  And you can do it in the product since 8.6 now.

Comment: At the time of writing this was not possible and deleting issues was only possible via the database.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow a Python script for doing it automatically using a library python-gitlab:

1. Install the library:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade python-gitlab
   ```
2. The script:

   ```
   import gitlab

   access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
   project_id = 00
   author_username = 'user.name'

   gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url='https://your-url.com/', 
   private_token=access_token)
   project = gl.projects.get(id=project_id)

   while True:
       issues = project.issues.list(iterator=True)
       if issues.total == 0:
           break

       for issue in issues:
           issue.delete()
           print(f'Deleted issue {issue.id}')
   ```